# I have trouble using cornerradius and borders on a textfield in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, border, textfield, cornerradius

I have a text field in swiftUI, and in order to make it more appealing I'd like to add a border and have rounded corners. But it doesn't seem to work like it's supposed to (see image). What did I miss?

[image: image 1]

I've tried putting .cornerradius() before .border(), but it had the same effect.

```
TextField("Text input goes here", text: $addMins)
    .padding(.all, 5.0)
    .background(View)
    .frame(width: 300.0, height: 35.0)
    .border(Color.green, width: 2)
    .cornerRadius(14)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So you want something like this?

```
TextField("Text Field", text: $text)
    .padding(4)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
            .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
    )
    .padding()
```

[image: textfield with green rounded border]

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the feedback, I was clearly not looking in the right direction.

Comment: I tried this and it's not possible to interact anymore with the Input

Answer (score 33):

Here a simple way:

---

[image]

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringOfTextField: String = String()

    var body: some View {
        
        TextField("Enter text . . .", text: $stringOfTextField)
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0)))
            .padding()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

By the way, if you need a stroked and corner radiused text field with a different background, here's a solution

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
    .padding()
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(Color.gray))
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
    )
    .foregroundColor(.black)
```

Comment: Stroke, Background and both needed Corner Radius!! Use It!!  whoooos this faaantasticcc mannnnn!!! 

Answer (score 6):

There is now a very easy built in way to do this with the modifier: `.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)`

Comment: This should be now the right answer